# is there a way to stop a user with dockerfile / docker-compose from assuming root inside of a container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, root, superuser

Is there any way to stop a user with dockerfile and docker-compose from assuming root inside of a docker container? The concern is, of course, security and least privilege and I would like to see if anyone has solved that issue. Thankyou ahead for your feedback.

Comment: TL;DR: no, anyone who can `docker run` anything can always get a root shell in your container or for that matter on the host.

Answer (score 3):

Docker run can be helpful here. When running containers you can specify the container process will run by xyz user who belongs to xyz group(optional).

--user , -u Username or UID (format: name|uid[:group|gid])

```
docker container run --rm \
  --user <uid>:<gid> \                        # Run as the given user
  my-repo/my-image:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the followings, you can use the `--user`/`-u` to specify a user (optionally with the group) in `$ docker run command`:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf583a

$ docker run --help

Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Run a command in a new container

Options:
...
...
...

  -u, --user string                    Username or UID (format: <name|uid>[:<group|gid>])
      --userns string                  User namespace to use
      --uts string                     UTS namespace to use
  -v, --volume list                    Bind mount a volume
      --volume-driver string           Optional volume driver for the container
      --volumes-from list              Mount volumes from the specified container(s)
  -w, --workdir string                 Working directory inside the container
```

So, you can use it like,

```
$ docker run --rm -it -u 65555 busybox id
uid=65555 gid=0(root)

$ docker run --rm -it -u 65555:65555 busybox id
uid=65555 gid=65555
```

Comment: (Also `-u 0` to explicitly request root, even if the image specified something different.)

Comment: yes, that is right.